# SQL wildcard underscore char not returning results

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wildcard

Anyone know why this query is returning zero results?  It should be returning about 93 results.

```
SELECT ps_stock_available.id_product FROM ps_stock_available
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product
WHERE description LIKE 'Christma_';
```

This query also returns **no results**:

```
SELECT ps_stock_available.id_product FROM ps_stock_available
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product
WHERE description LIKE 'Christma%';
```

This query returns **93 results**:

```
SELECT ps_stock_available.id_product FROM ps_stock_available
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product
WHERE description LIKE '%Christma%';
```

I am working in phpMyAdmin ver. 4.7.7 SQL query box of MySQL version 5.6.41-84.1.

Comment: ah, ok.  Sorry, I should have seen that.  Rookie mistake.  Thank you!

Comment: You can take help from this url https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly don't have any `description` field which has its value starting from `Christma`.

`LIKE 'Christma%'` and `LIKE 'Christma_'` expects the value to start from `Christma` with one or more characters on the right side of it. There should be no characters (no even whitespace characters) on the left side of the `Christma`. Also note that, `_` wildcard expects exactly one character.

For eg, if `description` column has `Christmas Carol` value. `LIKE 'Christma%'` will match the value; while `LIKE 'Christma_'` will not, as it expects exactly one character only after `Christma`.

`LIKE '%Christma%'` expects zero or many character on the either sides of `Christma`, in order to be able to match.

From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html):

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use `_` to match any single
>   character and `%` to match an arbitrary number of characters (including
>   zero characters). In MySQL, SQL patterns are case-insensitive by
>   default.

Comment: Not totally correct. The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters. But this could depend on dialect.

Comment: @triplem . . . The definition of `%` does not depend on the database.

Comment: I was unsure about this one. Thanks for the clarification.